# Lifeless, but Alive

Tags: riddle, word, steganography, meta-knowledge

Lifeless, but alive,
An aura of death surrounding.
[image: LIES]
Flies and maggots prosper,
Unmoving, unyielding.
[image: LEAVES OF THREE]
Limbs of crimson,
ever grieving.
[image: LET THEM BE]
In danger,
A stigma.
[image: WHO AM I]
Of whom do I speak?
[image: BOTH ANSWERS]
Hints from BeastlyGerbil's answer:

> Realm of flora. | Read it again. No, really! | The answer is large, but not quite a tree. | Who says it's poison?

Comment: For anyone who thinks this a simple riddle, I advise you check a bit closer...

Comment: *"Of whom do I speak?"* Beautiful writing. $(+1)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So by

> clicking edit or the gaps between paragraphs it can be seen there are two answers.

My first suggestion would be

> A tree? In particular a tree in autumn

But the better answer suggested by @Sensoray is

> The [Stinking Corpse Lily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafflesia_arnoldii)

Lifeless, but alive,
An aura of death surrounding.

> The flower is a 'corpse' but alive as it is a flower. It stinks or rotting corpses.

Flies and maggots prosper,
Unmoving, unyielding.

> The smell of rotting meat attracts many flies

Limbs of crimson,
ever grieving.

> The flower is the biggest flower in the world and has giant red leaves

In danger,
A stigma.

> In the middle of the red flower is the stigma. Red also symbolises danger.

---

And as for the second answer:

> It is poison ivy.

The hidden riddle is

> The words lie
> Leaves of three
> Let them be
> Who am I?
> Give me both answers!

The answer is

> Posion ivy, which has three leaves and should be avoided

Comment: You found out the trick much sooner than I expected! You are close. rot13(cbvfba vil vf pbeerpg sbe gur uvqqra nafjre. Fnl "va qnatre" naq erivfvg jung gung pbhyq zrna.)

Comment: @iiiidk I almost always click edit to look for hidden clues straight away, experience has taught me thats a good thing to do :) Ive edited the second answer. I'm guessing you are looking for a particular tree... I'll see if I can think of any 'dangerous' trees that fit

Comment: Maybe not quite a tree, but flora for sure! Save you some researching time.

Comment: @iiiidk thanks! Taking a brief look on wikipedia shows that there are *a lot* of poisonous plants - and nearly all of them seem to fit. Am I missing an obvious clue in the riddle?

Comment: Who says its poisonous?

Comment: @iiiidk hmmm... guessing I'm barking up the wrong tree **ba dum tss* :) ) I'll have another go then

Comment: @iiiidk okay I have a good idea of what it could be (rot13 - n cbccl - naq gur evqqyr vf gb qb jvgu gur jne) but just wanted to run that by you so I'm not extending my answer incorrectly... would that be right?

Comment: Alas. rot13(Gur evqqyr vf nyy nobhg gur nafjre; ab jne be bgure fhowrpgf urer. Zhnunun).

Comment: @iiiidk then I think its fair to say you have me stumped (*ba dum tss* again sorry :) )

Comment: I'll start the beginning of the hint train in ~four hours (at work, LOL); hope to see you then :)

Comment: First thought is rot13(Enssyrfvn neabyqvv)

Comment: @Sensoray thats a very good idea. You are most likely right, I'll add it and see

Comment: @Sensoray That would be correct!

Comment: @iiiidk editted. Well done Sensoray!